# IBk with custom similarity function as a recommender system

Tags: java, machine-learning, weka, recommendation-engine, knn

I'm trying to implement a recommender system based on a content-based similarity function (which uses description logics). 
Using this similarity function I built a similarity matrix for all the items of the dataset.
I decided to use this kind of information in order to implement a KNN classifier.

I'm using the Weka's implementation of the [KNN](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/lazy/IBk.html) and I implemented my similarity function extending [NormalizableDistance](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/core/NormalizableDistance.html). **It simply gets the distance score between two instance and returns it, because has been already computed**.

Using this function to construct my classifier in this way:

```
IBk knn = new IBk(numNeigh);
knn.getNearestNeighbourSearchAlgorithm().setDistanceFunction(new MyCustomFunction());
```

In this context, I'm not able to understand how should I use my dataset. 
My dataset is in the form:

```
 (user_id, item_id)
```

where each pair represents that a user has seen an item (implicit feedback).

If I try to construct a *Instances* object using the dataset that I have, I'm not able to run appropriately the KNN algorithm because each instance is not an item for which can be used the similarity function.

So I should create a dataset which contains only the items' ids of all those items that the user likes and build the classifier  with only this one.

Is it correct or I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to use a one-class classifier for each user, e.g. a SVM. It could be trained by using the descriptions of all items the user have seen. These can be ranked by its interior distance from the hypersphere enclosing them (the radius). The greater distance, the greater ranking. Thus, items outside the hypersphere wouldn't be recommended. If you had extra metadata indicating how interested the user has been in each seen item (e.g. observation time), it woud be possible using this information for downranking items or even discarding outliers.

Comment: I've got already a specific distance function. I need to use it in a well-known classification algorithm. So do you think that a one-class algorithm is a good choice? Can you give me some reference?

Comment: Hi... I have read several authors. I think the book by Taylor and Cristianini (Kernel Methods for pattern Analysis) is a very good starting point. It is pretty easy to understand. Specificly for one-class classification in NLP, you can see http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=944808 I hope it helps.